Docker & Gulp Browser Sync
I'm migrating my WordPress projects from Wamp to Docker ( WSL) and I have problems getting Gulp to work properly. The changes to CSS are not seen, although Gulp successfully compiles assets as well as shows BrowserSync: "connected" notice in the browser when accessed on localhost:3000. The changes to CSS are not seen even if I hard reload the page. However, the changes are seen if I edit theme.css file directly and then hard reload.
So, it's like if the theme.css file is touched by Gulp the changes won't be seen in browser. I have no clue what could be causing this 
This is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mariadb:10.5.9
    logging:
      driver: none
    command: ["--max-allowed-packet=512M"]
    volumes:
      - "./data/db:/var/lib/mysql:delegated"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    restart: always
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  litespeed:
    image: litespeedtech/openlitespeed:1.8.1-lsphp81
    container_name: litespeed_bl
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./lsws/conf:/usr/local/lsws/conf
      - ./lsws/admin-conf:/usr/local/lsws/admin/conf
      - ./bin/container:/usr/local/bin
      - ./sites:/var/www/vhosts/
      - ./acme:/root/.acme.sh/
      - ./logs:/usr/local/lsws/logs/
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 443:443/udp
      - 7080:7080
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: ${TimeZone}
    networks:
      - default
  phpmyadmin:
    image: bitnami/phpmyadmin:5.2.0-debian-11-r43
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
    environment:
         DATABASE_HOST: mysql
         UPLOAD_LIMIT: 500M 
         PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 500M
         PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE: 500M
    restart: always
    networks:
      - default
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    logging:
      driver: none
    # command: redis-server --requirepass 8b405f60665e48f795752e534d93b722
    volumes:
      - ./redis/data:/var/lib/redis
      - ./redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    environment:
      - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master
    restart: always
    networks:
      - default
  node:
    image: node:14
    working_dir: /var/www/vhosts/localhost/html/wp-content/themes/wp-theme/
    volumes:
      - ./sites:/var/www/vhosts/
    command: sh -c "npm install -g gulp@4.0.2  && npm install && gulp watch"
    restart: "no"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
        - "3001:3001"
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge

This us browsersync config my gulpfile.js:
function browser_sync() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: 'litespeed:80'
    });
}

I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong 
